# Include not functioning like I am expecting

Tags: php, include

The below gives me a fatal error saying that "mymail" was not found.

Any ideas why? Looks right to me.

**mailreq.php**

```
include("mail.php");
$r = mymail("test","test");
```

**mail.php**

```
function mymail($body, $reqtype)
{
 //blah blah
}
```

EDIT:
For some reason, this version of php doesn't see `<? ?>` as valid shorthand tags. I changed it to `<?php ?>` and it sees the functions now.

Comment: is it failing on the `include()` line or the function call line?

Comment: the function call line. I've tried creating a small test file (test.php) with a one line function inside. Same issue.

Comment: @dnagirl: include doesn't issue a fatal error.

Comment: I tried moving up a dir by putting include '../test.php' and now it complains failed to open stream, no such directory etc.
So it's finding the file.

Comment: default PHP config is to have short tags turned off.

Answer (score 4):

If `mymail()` wasn't found, the problem is presumably with the path to the included file. You might try using `require()` instead, that way the script will (if I remember rightly) stop running if the required file isn't found.

Comment: Or, better, `require_once()`, which only includes it once. And yes, using `require` rather than `include` will throw a fatal error if it can't include it.

Comment: @Slokun, absolutely, I was only using it as part of the debug process, rather than as an option for clean code =) But it's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong with what you posted.  Are you sure it wasn't some little mistake somewhere - like maybe you forgot the `<?php` and  `?>` in the mail.php file?  Or maybe a pathing issue?

Comment: Interesting. He should see the output though.

Answer (score 0):

You're either not passing the correct path of mail.php or there is no mymail function in mail.php. What are the absolute paths of mail.php and mailreq.php?

It appears your script **requires** mail.php, so use `require 'mail.php'` (or whatever the correct path is).

Comment: mail.php and mailreq.php are all in the same directory.
Using WAMPServer if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the error `... was not found.` is most likely because you are not specifying the correct path for the `mail.php`. Make sure that you are specifying the correct path.